# Have I been terminated?

Tags: termination

I am working with a bank in india.

I stole money from my friends bag and when the cctv footage was checked by mentor, I kept all the money in her bag and everyone came to know my friend found her money.

There was days holidays except 2nd day, 1st day my colleagues were talking on whatsapp group chat & on personal chat. The 2nd day i was unable to go to the office. My contact with my colleagues was very less then usual, I was in guilt & afraid.

Was not able to decide what to do, whether to go to office or not. I went back office on 6th day, it was seems to be everything normal but I was in guilt and nobody was in my touch. My colleagues were indicating that they were very busy in work & can't talk. I decided to quit the job and asked my mentor for my resignation. He told me to come back the afternoon.

At lunchtime my colleagues came to me and said that they were going out for lunch and asked me to join. After lunchtime, my mentor called me and I went to see them.

They said that whatever happened on that day, they've found some evidence in CCTV footage and told me not to go anywhere, since they've called the cops.
I decided to confess to not make it worse.

I confessed everything to them and I also confessed to my friend stating whatever happened on that day, was done by me and I'm sorry for that, it was mistake. She agreed and forgave me.

My mentor was saying that they would be terminating me. I cried and requested them not to do this it was my mistake.

After long time they asked me to give confession letter. And said me to go home they've sent that letter to HR.
Now it has been a month and I still don't know whether they're terminating me or not. Tried calling them also but they don't answer. Sometimes there is a feeling like I must quit, there is no career left for me.

Since this is my first job. I don't know what to do, What will be the procedure? Ami I still the employee of bank? Should I apply to different job or don't & also i'll apply then whether I will get job or wont? Did they terminate me?

Comment: Just to confirm, were you still working for any length of time after sending the confession letter? They told you to 'go home' but have you returned to the office since then?

Comment: I was working there for one and half year. While sending home they said whatever formality is there it has to be done by/with HR. But till now there is no call I received from anyone

Comment: So you've been sitting at home for a month now, wondering if you're still employed?  Have you still been receiving pay cheques?  (I would expect at least one deposit should have gone through in this time, if they are still paying you.)

Comment: Yes I'm sitting home with this concern. I did not received my salary for last month.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, your work with that company ended.**

In order to get legal proof, tell the company (HR) that you haven't received their letter of termination yet.

In the unlikely event that they didn't fire you, they'll let you know.

It is understandable to feel desperate and your job hunt won't be easy, but you will get other chances in life.

Make sure to prove yourself worthy of that.

It is not the end of the world and certainly no cause to end your young life over a mistake in a moment of weakness.

Good luck and behave yourself honorably, things will get better.

Answer (score 3):

## In this circumstance you are lucky to not have been arrested, never mind fired.

What you did is known as a 'gross misconduct' offence. In most employment contracts in the West, this is the one scenario where they can let you go without written warning, notice or compensation of any kind. In India, there might be other scenarios where this can happen but this one here is still a thing.

> My mentor was saying that they would be terminating me.

This right here is all the notice that you need. You need to get back on the job ladder. I would advise moving away from the finance industry for now as you are likely dealing with criminal charges of theft, and having that on your record so recently will raise alarm bells for prospective employers